# How to pass data along with the back button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile, we can easily create a "Back" button with data-rel="back" or data-add-back-btn="true"
However, is there a way for us to also pass back some custom data when user click the back button?

One common scenario is that we use Ajax to transition from page1 to page2. In page2, user performs some actions, and the results of such actions in page2 should be passed back to page1 when user clicks "Back" button.

So far, I have not being able to find a proper solutions. The plugin jquerymobile-router by azicchetti is useful when you want to ajax pass url parameters from page1 to page2 (so that page2 has some knowledge from page1). But I am not sure how it can apply in reverse (page2 back to page1)

Comment: Back buttons traditionally pop the current context from a stack and revert to the previous context.  It sounds like what you really want is to POST to the previous URL.  I don't know jQuery well enough to say that's how it implements its back button, but I'm guessing you'll have to use some other mechanism to do what you want.

Comment: The POST or GET (any server related actions) is presumed completed in page2, so page1 is merely doing something on the client side with the result from page2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Cookies or Sessions for this. Another possibilty could be: local storage.

Comment: The only concern with Cookies/Sessions/Local Storage is the reliability. I mean people can disable Cookies on mobile, and refuse Local Storage for a given web site. As for sessions, if mobile loses connection, the client would fail. 

I am considering having a global JavaScript variable (i.e. var MyWebApp = {}), and share that global variable between pages. That won't work if user refresh the page though.

Comment: Well, I ended up with three level of fallback mechanism
In the index mobile page, I have a global js variable + some logic that deals with setting/getting localStorage. In addition, I also load up jquery.cookie.js. Thus, inside the pageshow event, I check
1. if the global variable has custom data I need. If not
2. check cookie for the data.. if not
3. check localStorage

Hopefully that should be sufficient.